# I want to show 2 data using if statement

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have 2 pages, in that 2 separate data is there. So using if condition I want to show them on one page when I give one URL.

```
if(this.$route.name  == "Locations"){
    this.currentComponent = "zone-index";
    this.currentComponent = "common-index";
}
```

Comment: could not understand your point can explain briefly

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components